# Is there any advantage to using an aggregate function filter using WHERE instead of HAVING?

Tags: sql

I have two queries in SQL:

```
SELECT PACKAGE, AVG(LIST_PRICE) AS AVERAGE_PRICE
FROM TABLE_OF_PRODUCTS
GROUP BY PACKAGE
HAVING AVG(LIST_PRICE) <= 10;
```

And

```
SELECT PACKAGE_PRICES.PACKAGE, PACKAGE_PRICES.AVERAGE_PRICE
FROM
    (SELECT PACKAGE, AVG(LIST_PRICE) AS AVERAGE_PRICE
     FROM TABLE_OF_PRODUCTS
     GROUP BY PACKAGE) AS PACKAGE_PRICES
WHERE PACKAGE_PRICES.AVERAGE_PRICE <= 10;
```

Both queries will return the packages of products that have an average price greater than or equal to 10. I'm learning SQL and I'm wondering if there's any advantage to using the second method.

Comment: This will provide examples of the differences https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-having-vs-where/?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAxaCvBhBaEiwAvsLmWHMwtPTfO3cI5n5B0d-ZSAPnmmqzPpnP29sTLtzAV2lYQnCWn2LtchoCuF4QAvD_BwE

Comment: I'd assume most dbms:s will end up doing the same execution anyway. In this case I'd go with the HAVING query. But if the expression was (much) more complex, I'd consider the derived table query.

Comment: Good optimizers will realize that the same expression is being used and therefore calculate it only once. The main concern is readability: a CTE is less readable, but a very complex aggregation being repeated many times is also less readable, so it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score -1):

An "aggregate function filter using WHERE" isn't valid syntax. In your example, you don't use an aggregate function with the WHERE clause, and instead you pull from a different table that presumably contains the same data that the aggregate function AVG would produce.

Comment: OP's query is valid syntax. There is no "aggregate function filter using WHERE".